# SharePoint 2019 App Icon Missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2019, apps-development

I was wondering if anyone has figured out how to configure add-in icons for SharePoint online/19?[image].  For sites deployed to 2016 instances I can see the icon configured in Visual studio.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the file name in /config/package-solution.js:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package-solution.schema.json",
    "solution": {
        "name": "...",
        "id": "...",
        "version": "...",
        "iconPath": "AppIcon.png",
        "skipFeatureDeployment": true
    },
    ...
}
```

And upload the 'AppIcon.png' to ./sharepoint folder of your solution.

Also, you can define iconPath as base64-encoded image.